# content loads behind sticky header instead of under

Tags: javascript, html, css

here's the link to the page
[jsbmac.com](http://jsbmac.com/) and here's the pen [codepen](https://codepen.io/brucemcminn/pen/vRJLJQ) but the images don't load there, just check the live version. Here's the relevant CSS

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 282px;
}

.content {
    padding: 26px;
    padding-top: 282px;
}
```

and here's the JavaScript

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
```

My question is how do I get the class="content" to load below the class="header" instead of under. The background gradient color is supposed to match the header color in the upper right hand corner like this
[screen shot, matched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syHVm.jpg)

but instead it looks like this
[screen shot, not matched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuzYt.jpg)

because the padding is needed to keep the images on top from being behind the .header. I think that's how w3schools had me do it.

If I remove the z-index I still need to create the extra padding for .sticky+.content and .content so that the images at the top aren't lost and the player controls end up on top of the header when scrolling, so that's not it. I figure there must be some way to fix the top part of .content to the bottom of .header but I don't know how.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

of course it will be under the header because it's `400px` high and has a fixed position in the top, adding a `margin-top` to your `.content` will fix the issue

Since the header has `position:fixed` , both it and `.content` are positioned relatively to the window, so the `margin-top` of the `.content`  has to be the same as the `header`'s height to be under it.

ps : reduce the `padding-top` of `.content`

```
.sticky + .content {
    padding-top: 60px;
    margin-top: 375px;
}
```

Comment: I re-did it with flex-box and dropped the JavaScript. Thanks.